# What is the URL for Firebase Cloud Messaging POST?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I am trying to send a Firebase POST request based on a topic I created, called "alert".

1. How does one determine which URL to send the post request to?
2. What authentication needs to be offered? I have tried the legacy server key and other keys found on the Firebase console but am not sure what to do.

Screenshots from Postman:
[image: POST body]
[image: POST header and error message]

Comment: You're not passing in an `Authorization` header, as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#authorize_http_requests

Comment: Comment your header parameters.